# Ethernet icon not showing in Ubuntu 2019.4

Tags: ubuntu

The ethernet icon is not showing on the desktop of Ubuntu 2019.4. I have installed it on my laptop Dell Inspiron 15.

[image]

Comment: So you're just missing the icon? Is anything else not working?

Comment: What is your image supposed to be showing us? If it’s just the ```ifconfig``` output, please just paste that into your question *as text.*